# always seeing an empty database after running my application

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Vb 2010 in designing my apps. I've connected my database with my application but I didn't use any code in the connection. I used Data source and Databinding property and when I save the data the database is always empty. Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Place a BindingNavigator component in your form and set it's binding source property to the same datasource of your other component.